# Best way to get info from Parse.com Cloud Code (Javascript SDK)

Tags: javascript, angular, parse-platform, back4app

I’ve been looking on parse documentations but I’m a bit confused.
I’ve been though this tutorial where it says I should make my backend operations though Cloud Code.

For my user profile Cloud Code I have the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getUserInfo",async(request) => {
  let currentUser = request.user;
  let query = new Parse.Query("User");
  query.equalTo("objectId",currentUser.id)  
  let results = await query.find({useMasterKey:true});
  if(results.length === 0) throw new Error('No results found!');  
  let user = results[0];  
  let userInfo = [];
  userInfo.push(
   {
     Location:user.get("location"),
     Bio:user.get("bio")
   });
   return userInfo;
});
```

And in the client side (I’m using Angular):

```
let response = Parse.Cloud.run('getUserInfo');
console.log(response);
```

I’m not sure how to read the response in the promise.
And right now I’m not even sure this is the best way to do it and I really haven’t found what I’m looking for on the web.
So I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```js
(async () => {
  const response = await Parse.Cloud.run('getUserInfo');
  console.log(response);
})();
```